# Using virsh to control KVM and openvz

Tags: kvm-virtualization, openvz, libvirt

On different servers I'm using virsh to manage openvz containers or KVM guests.

No I have a server with both, KVM **and** openvz installed and would like to controll both with virsh.

I can't figure out how to 'switch' between openvz and KVM. Currently (maybe because I first installed openvz)

```
# virsh list
```

only displays my vz containers.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose which hypervisor to connect to with the `-c` option.

For instance for KVM:

```
virsh -c qemu:///system list
```

And for openvz:

```
virsh -c opencz:///system list
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I added the second option just to be complete :)